# Terraform: deployment of EBS CSI driver with EKS module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I'm trying to deploy `EBS CSI Driver` using [EKS module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest), there's example code which I found:

```
module "ebs_csi_irsa_role" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-role-for-service-accounts-eks"

  role_name             = "ebs-csi"
  attach_ebs_csi_policy = true

  oidc_providers = {
    ex = {
      provider_arn               = module.eks.oidc_provider_arn
      namespace_service_accounts = ["kube-system:aws-ebs-csi-driver"]
    }
  }
}

module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 18.6"

  (..)

  cluster_addons = {
    aws-ebs-csi-driver = {
      addon_version     = "v1.17.0-eksbuild.1"
      resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
      service_account_role_arn = module.ebs_csi_irsa_role.iam_role_arn
    }
  }
}
```

But there's dependency cycle here - IAM role required EKS, and EKS requires IAM role. How to do that properly?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using local variables:

```
locals {
  ebs_csi_irsa_role = module.ebs_csi_irsa_role.iam_role_arn
}

module "ebs_csi_irsa_role" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-role-for-service-accounts-eks"

  role_name             = "ebs-csi"
  attach_ebs_csi_policy = true

  oidc_providers = {
    ex = {
      provider_arn               = module.eks.oidc_provider_arn
      namespace_service_accounts = ["kube-system:aws-ebs-csi-driver"]
    }
  }
}

module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 18.6"

  (..)

  cluster_addons = {
    aws-ebs-csi-driver = {
      addon_version     = "v1.17.0-eksbuild.1"
      resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
      service_account_role_arn = local.ebs_csi_irsa_role
    }
  }
}
```